# Generating/Maintaining a typescript definition file for my react typescript component library

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am building a react library in typescript and i want to provide consumers of this library a typescript definition file.

How do i make sure the typescript definition file is always correct an matching the js code?

Or if my components are written in typescript is there a way to generate a single d.ts file from all the generated d.ts files the compiler generated for me?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are the author of the library, it's extremely easy to provide and maintain the definitions. It works the same way regardless of the library you're using (such as React).

1. Create `.d.ts` file

---

You can create a `.d.ts` file by passing **`-d`** to compiler arguments or adding **`declaration: true`** in your `tsconfig.json`.

2. Add definitions to `package.json`

---

Add field named `typings` to your `project.json`, e.g. **`"typings": "./index.d.ts"`** (`./index.d.ts` is actually the default value if `typings` is omitted).

---

TypeScript compiler will automatically use provided typings if the user installs your library via NPM.

More info:
[Writing Declaration Files](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/writing-declaration-files.html)
[Typings for NPM packages](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/publishing.html)

Comment: thanks, but specifying the **decleration: true** flag creates a definition file for each file and not a single index.d.ts

Comment: If you need to concatenate `.d.ts` files, you can use https://github.com/SitePen/dts-generator

Comment: i looked at the project https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/material-ui
Are the authors create the typings manually for each component?
Or are they using a automatic tool for it?
I want to expose a type definition for all my react typescript components i wrote.

Comment: If you include your typings in the NPM module itself, everyone can use it automatically. DefinitelyTyped repository contains external typings for the JS modules that do not include them.

Comment: Do i need to make a single d.ts file or just publishing multiple tsx files for example will suffice?

Comment: As far as I remember, multiple `.tsx` files won't work, you have to provide a `.d.ts` file

Answer (score 8):

as mentioned Here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65629179/10606346

The easiest way to have a `.d.ts` file out of the box with React is to put it in `src` folder and name it `global.d.ts` like:

`src/global.d.ts`

Answer (score 2):

Add this inside your tsconfig.json

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationDir": "build" // the name of the build folder generated
    }
}
```

Comment: This helped alongside the response [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65629179/6793883)