# Typescript react - Could not find a declaration file for module ''react-materialize'. 'path/to/module-name.js' implicitly has an any type

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-2

I am trying to import components from react-materialize as -

```
import {Navbar, NavItem} from 'react-materialize';
```

But when the webpack is compiling my `.tsx` it throws an error for the above as -

```
ERROR in ./src/common/navbar.tsx
(3,31): error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-materi
alize'. 'D:\Private\Works\Typescript\QuickReact\node_modules\react-materialize\l
ib\index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

Is there any resolution for this? I'm unsure how to resolve this import statement to work with `ts-loader` and webpack.

The `index.js` of react-materialize looks likes this. But how do I resolve this for the module import in my own files?

https://github.com/react-materialize/react-materialize/blob/master/src/index.js

Comment: You need to install the typings/types for the package (npm install @types/react-materialize). However, it looks like this doesn't exist yet, so you may need to create it yourself. I found this article helpful - https://templecoding.com/blog/2016/03/31/creating-typescript-typings-for-existing-react-components/

Comment: @T Mitchell so does that mean any kind of types which we are missing we never would be able to compile webpack without this creating these types ? There should be some way ?

Comment: There is a way - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38224232/how-to-consume-npm-modules-from-typescript

Comment: this seems like a bit of a workaround to me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not find a declaration file for module 'module-name'. '/path/to/module-name.js' implicitly has an 'any' type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41292559/could-not-find-a-declaration-file-for-module-module-name-path-to-module-nam)

Answer (score 150, accepted):

For those who wanted to know that how did I overcome this . I did a hack kind of stuff .

Inside my project I created a folder called `@types` and added it to tsconfig.json for find all required types from it . So it looks somewhat like this -

```json
"typeRoots": [
  "../node_modules/@types",
  "../@types"
]
```

And inside that I created a file called `alltypes.d.ts` . To find the unknown types from it . so for me these were the unknown types and I added it over there.

```
declare module 'react-materialize';
declare module 'react-router';
declare module 'flux';
```

So now the typescript didn't complain about the types not found anymore . :) win win situation now :)

Comment: I missed the part about it being in a separate file. Seems like putting those `declare` statements in a file named `index.d.ts` fixed it for me. I didn't have to touch typeRoots.

Comment: That works just fine but it causes issues when using `require ` for other stuff like images. Basically, it just doesn't allow you to use `require` for anything.

Comment: this solution no longer works with latest TS. `nvalid module name in augmentation. Module 'some-dumb-lib-with-no-types' resolves to an untyped module at '/path/to/module', which cannot be augmented.`

Comment: Something also worth mentioning: depending on the location of your source, you may also need to add "../types" to your "includes" array

Comment: but when I run the app it is complaining with the same error message, how to resolve it?

Comment: If you would like to disable it site wide you can instead edit tsconfig.json and set noImplicitAny to false.

Comment: I have issues with `react-countdown-clock`, created `@types` folder and did all the above steps. still getting the same error.

Comment: This all worked for me except for the additional config added to the tsconfig.json. Rather than using the example in the answer, I had to set the @types location in the "paths" value rather than the "typeRoots" value, i.e.

{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "paths": {
            "*" : ["src/@t`ypes/*"]
        }
    }
}

Comment: anyone has luck with the latest version of ts?

Answer (score 205):

I had a similar error but for me it was `react-router`. Solved it by installing types for it.

```
npm install --save @types/react-router
```

Error:

```
(6,30): error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-router'. '\node_modules\react-router\index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

If you would like to disable it site wide you can instead edit `tsconfig.json` and set `noImplicitAny` to `false`.

Comment: Although there is currently no such @types/react-navigation-tabs package yet, still the mentioned `"noImplicitAny": false,` did disable it (I got this issue because of using react-native init MyProject --template typescript, I think so at least) 

Comment: or `yarn add @types/react-router --dev`

Comment: ````yarn add @types/react-router-dom```` Fixed it for me when using create-react-app

Comment: Best answer. Had the same issue with `react-slick` as my project is a TypeScript project. Fix `npm i --save-dev @types/react-slick`

Comment: I had a similar problem with `jest-axe`. Solved by installing `@types/jest-axe`.

Answer (score 96):

I've had a same problem with react-redux types. The simplest solution
 was add to tsconfig.json:

```
"noImplicitAny": false
```

### Example:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "lib": ["es6"],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmit": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "esnext",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "babel.config.js", "metro.config.js", "jest.config.js"]
}
```

Comment: this worked great in `IntelliJ` IDE, but the custom `typeRoots` method (which is the accepted answer) did even work in `VS Code` IDE

Comment: I think this is a hack, though this solved the problem but Is there any valid and permanent solution for this problem?

Comment: I think this is the best solution to this problem, I don't think it's viable to npm i every package that throws the err

Comment: Work perfect on VSC with react using typescript

Comment: This is a very bad practice, as the `any` type just ignores Typescript linting. So what's the point? It's a step back toward normal javascript, instead of using Typescript. For me the following answer solved it, and is considered much better: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41462729/typescript-react-could-not-find-a-declaration-file-for-module-react-material#answer-62194561

Comment: Problem solving begins from a simplest answer to avoid blockers during development. Next step is to find more elegant and focussed solution

Answer (score 61):

Make sure to stop your react local server and start it again after doing the following:

1- Create  `.d.ts` file manually, you just need to do the following:

2 - enter `src folder`

3 - create `global.d.ts` file

4 - declare modules in it like:

```
declare module 'module-name';
```

I answered it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65580300/10606346) before and it was nice

Comment: Thanks! This works the best out of all the solutions mentioned here

Comment: Make sure to stop your react local server and start it again if it still doesn't work after doing the above. `npm start`

Comment: This helped alongside the response [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72770743/6793883)

Answer (score 60):

If there is no `@types/<package>` for the module you are using, you may easily circumvent the issue by adding a `// @ts-ignore` comment above i.e.

```
// @ts-ignore
import { Navbar, NavItem } from 'react-materialize';
```

Alternatively you may create the missing `@types/<package>` following:

[declaration files publishing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/publishing.html)

[DefinitelyTyped how can i contribute](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped#how-can-i-contribute)

Comment: This package doesn't have a `@types` available yet BTW. Created an issue on the repo... https://github.com/geelen/react-snapshot/issues/131

Comment: In 2022: `Do not use "@ts-ignore" because it alters compilation errors`

Answer (score 35):

In my case I had a problem with react, so I started doing:

`npm install @types/react`

and then to the

`npm install @types/react-dom`

This worked for me

Comment: Even tough they were already installed, re-running those commands solved the problem for me.

Comment: Basically, it updates your existing packages when you re-run the commands. That was the reason the problem is solved.

Comment: `npm install @types/react` was enough in my case. Thx!

Answer (score 27):

Just install the necessary types for react and it should solve the error.

if you are using yarn:

```
yarn add @types/react @types/react-dom @types/react-router-dom -D
```

if you are using npm:

```
npm install @types/react @types/react-dom @types/react-router-dom --save-dev
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me. Surprising that I had to do this as I had created the react app using the command 
npx create-react-app react-quiz --template typescript

I thought this would be enough to take care of all dependencies

Answer (score 8):

I had this same problem but not necessarily relating to typescript, so I struggled a bit with these different options. I am making a very basic create-react-app using a specific module `react-portal-tooltip,` getting similar error:

> Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-portal-tooltip'. '/node_modules/react-portal-tooltip/lib/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
>   Try `npm install @types/react-portal-tooltip` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'react-portal-tooltip';`ts(7016)

I tried many steps first - adding various `.d.ts` files, various npm installs.

But what eventually worked for me was `touch src/declare_modules.d.ts`
then in `src/declare_modules.d.ts`:

```js
declare module "react-portal-tooltip";
```

and in `src/App.js`:

```js
import ToolTip from 'react-portal-tooltip';
// import './declare_modules.d.ts'
```

I struggled a bit with the different locations to use this general 'declare module' strategy (I am very much a beginner) so I think this will work with different options but I am included paths for what worked work me.

I initially thought `import './declare_modules.d.ts'` was necessary. Although now it seems like it isn't! But I am including the step in case it helps someone.

*This is my first stackoverflow answer so I apologize for the scattered process here and hope it was still helpful! :)*

Comment: This is really neat and simple. Thank you. Keep up the good work!

Answer (score 7):

All you need to do is run the below script. Then, remove/re-install the module that you want to use.

```
npm install --save @types/react-redux
```

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a @types/react-materialize available

Answer (score 7):

Had the same error with `react-router-dom`.

This error occurs when you're working on a typescript project, default modules doesn't come with types that are needed with typescript.

So I searched on npmjs.com a package named `@types/react-router-dom` if it's not react-router-dom you're seeking for then replace the `react-router-dom` by your untyped module.

Seek for the last version on the npm website, then add this in your `package.json` like so :

```json
[...]
"dependencies": {
    [...]
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.8",
    [...]
  },
[...]
```

Once it's done, run `yarn install`

Then it should rocks !

Comment: You can also add it in "devDependencies": `"devDependencies": { "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.8" }`

Comment: Note: Add types module to devDependencises

Answer (score 6):

I had this issue when I added `react-router-dom` to the new CRA app using typescript. After I added `@types/react-router`, the issue was fixed.

Comment: What to do after installing this?

Answer (score 5):

A more hacky way is to add eg., in boot.tsx the line

```
import './path/declare_modules.d.ts';
```

with

```
declare module 'react-materialize';
declare module 'react-router';
declare module 'flux';
```

in `declare_modules.d.ts`

It works but other solutions are better IMO.

Answer (score 5):

> Could not find a declaration file for module 'react/jsx-runtime'

If someone's having this error, then you'll be surprised to know that when creating react app with `create-react-app`, it only shows `@types/react` in `package.json`. But if you check inside the `node_modules/@types` folder, **you'll not find** any folder of `react`.

Solution is to just wipe out the `node_modules` folder completely and reinstall - `npm install` or maybe can go with the individual module installation - `npm install @types/react`.

Comment: The most relevant answer that completely solves the problem, thanks!

Comment: Cool! Tnx! `npm install -D @types/react` IMO would be better

Comment: @tropikan4 yeah but who knows if in future just like `@types/react` some other module is also absent then we can go with `npm install`

Answer (score 4):

Also, this error gets fixed if the package you're trying to use has it's own type file(s) **and** it's listed it in the *package.json* `typings` attribute

Like so:

```
{
  "name": "some-package",
  "version": "X.Y.Z",
  "description": "Yada yada yada",
  "main": "./index.js",

  "typings": "./index.d.ts",

  "repository": "https://github.com/yadayada.git",
  "author": "John Doe",
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true
}
```

Answer (score 3):

What I did was run the following commands from nodejs command prompt while in the project folder directory:

1. `npm init`
2. `npm install -g webpack`
3. `npm install --save react react-dom @types/react @types/react-dom`
4. `npm install --save-dev typescript awesome-typescript-loader source-map-loader`
5. `npm install ajv@^6.0.0`
6. `npm i react-html-id`
7. import the package(in node modules) in App.js file by adding the code: `import UniqueId from 'react-html-id';`

I did the above(although I already had npm installed) and it worked!

Answer (score 3):

I got it after lots of trouble
In react app
there will be a react-app-env.d.ts file in src folder
just declare module there

```
/// <reference types="react-scripts" />
declare module 'react-color/lib/components/alpha/AlphaPointer'
```

Answer (score 3):

Created a file called index.d.ts in the src folder and added

```
declare module 'react-materialize';
```

then included the file in tsconfig.json file like:

```
 "include": [
   "src",
   "index.d.ts"
 ]
```

Answer (score 1):

These are notes if you want to just declare types for a node module where typings are not available.

> Solution--->

1. create a global.d.ts file inside src directory.
2. because typescript is already watching src directory
3. and thus we avoid explicitly stating in tsconfig.json to load particular type files also, because in doing so we other default typing location can get overriden

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem, The simplest solution was

`npm i --save-dev @types/react-router && npm i --save-dev @types/react-router-dom`

Answer (score 0):

For my case the issue was that the types were not getting added to package.json file under ***devDependencies*** to fix it I ran `npm install --save-dev @types/react-redux` note the `--save-dev`

Answer (score 0):

try adding to tsconfig.json file: `"noImplicitAny": false`
worked for me

Comment: You're basically disabling all of the goodness provided by TypeScript by doing this.  Why not just use regular JS?

Answer (score 0):

In case if you have problem with react npm install --save @types/react`npm install --save @types/react`

Answer (score 0):

Like this one:

```
{
  "name": "some-package",
  "version": "X.Y.Z",
  "description": "Yada yada yada",
  "main": "./index.js",
  
  "typings": "./index.d.ts",
  
  "repository": "https://github.com/yadayada.git",
  "author": "John Doe",
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true
}
```

Also, this error gets fixed if the package you're trying to use has it's own type file(s) **and** it's listed it in the *package.json* `typings` attribute

Comment: do not understand your solution, what are you suggesting?

Answer (score 0):

Try `npm i --save-dev @types/react-materialize` if it exists or add a new declaration (`.d.ts`) file containing `declare module 'react-materialize';`

Answer (score 0):

You can find a proper solution over [here](https://github.com/kareemaly/react-items-carousel/issues/65#issuecomment-972763320). You just need to replace `react-items-carousel` with `react-materialize`.

Answer (score -2):

works just fine

```
npm install @types/react-materialize
```

Comment: there are no types in for react-materialize

Answer (score -2):

There might be cases when some dependencies doest not have types and ts forces you to include types for that. There is a workaround to resolve the issue, which is to use javascript instead.

e.g.

`import {Charts} from "react-charts";` //error: Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-charts'.

Workaround: `const ReactChart = require("react-charts");` //no-error

Comment: you can write js in a ts file. It won't show you any errors. It is compiled to javascript only in the end after all.