# How to enable IDE auto-completion for java-script npm packages (which do not have .d.ts files) in type-script?

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, visual-studio-code

I have created an empty `react-native` project but using type-script (like `react-native init MyApp --template typescript`), then installed on that `react-navigation-tabs` package, and the problem which I am facing is:

```
TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-navigation-tabs'.
'.../node_modules/react-navigation-tabs/src/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
Try `npm install @types/react-navigation-tabs` if it exists
or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'react-navigation-tabs';`
```

I did also try `npm install --save-dev @types/react-navigation-tabs`, and since no such package did exist,
for now I did workaround it like suggested in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41631658/8740349).

But coming back to the question in the title,  it is really painful, I mean the information that the `IDE` needs to provide auto-completion are there, in the `node_modules/react-navigation-tabs/src/index.js` file, like:

```js
/* @flow */
/* eslint-disable import/no-commonjs */

module.exports = {
  /**
   * Navigators
   */
  get createBottomTabNavigator() {
    return require('./navigators/createBottomTabNavigator').default;
  },
  get createMaterialTopTabNavigator() {
    return require('./navigators/createMaterialTopTabNavigator').default;
  },

  /**
   * Views
   */
  get BottomTabBar() {
    return require('./views/BottomTabBar').default;
  },
  get MaterialTopTabBar() {
    return require('./views/MaterialTopTabBar').default;
  },

  /**
   * Utils
   */
  get createTabNavigator() {
    return require('./utils/createTabNavigator').default;
  },
};
```

How can we make the IDE (e.g. `VS Code`) show auto-completion using the data it can find in the existing `node_modules/react-navigation-tabs/src/index.js` file ?

**Edit:** Also, created a request/question [on github](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/72636).

Comment: Those aren't types, where do you see types?

Comment: sorry @PatrickRoberts, I do not know how to call them, but still, there are obviously usable information `exported` for the module, lets say, I want the IDE to recognize them.

Comment: TypeScript can only infer types from `.ts` files or `.d.ts` files, the `@flow` directive means nothing to it.

Comment: Is there any `node-module` that can create such files for us? (although, the `package.json` of the modules contain something like `"main": "src/index.js"`, and the IDE even knows where it exactly should start, but as long as the auto-completion works, I am happy with anything)