# TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined with commerce.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

I have been trying to solve this error with several ways, since other people had similar outputs, but still couldn’t do it completely.

I am creating an e-commerce site integrating commerce.js, after importing from '@chec/commerce.js' I had a warning (VS):

```
Could not find a declaration file for module '@chec/commerce.js'. '/Users/e-commerce/node_modules/@chec/commerce.js/lib/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm install @types/chec__commerce.js` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module '@chec/commerce.js';`ts(7016)
```

Whenever I fired the localhost, as I was expecting, I saw a related error message, not exactly the same though (will reproduce it below). 
Therefore my thought was: fixing the error message in VS, will most likely fix this one as well.
I manage to solve the warning by adding the new declaration file (because it seems that the package mentioned there doesn’t exist yet)
So, I thought it was that, then I fired the server and the output is exactly the same as before.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined
new e
node_modules/@chec/commerce.js/lib/index.js:1
```

Now, apparently is the first line of the file index.js in node_modules. Ok, what does it say then? (I will write here more than only the first line, just in case)

```
    var _objectWithoutProperties=require("@babel/runtime/helpers/objectWithoutProperties"),_toConsumableArray=require("@babel/runtime/helpers/toConsumableArray"),_typeof=require("@babel/runtime/helpers/typeof"),_defineProperty=require("@babel/runtime/helpers/defineProperty"),_classCallCheck=require("@babel/runtime/helpers/classCallCheck"),_createClass=require("@babel/runtime/helpers/createClass"),_regeneratorRuntime=require("@babel/runtime/regenerator"),_asyncToGenerator=require("@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator"),axios=require("axios");function _interopDefaultLegacy(e){return e&&"object"==typeof e&&"default"in e?e:{default:e}}
```

But this is not the only one, below, another one complaining about the commerce module still

```
Module.<anonymous>
src/lib/commerce.js:4
  1 | // @ts-ignore
  2 | import Commerce from "@chec/commerce.js";
  3 | 
> 4 | export const commerce = new Commerce(
  5 |   process.env.REACT_APP_CHEC_PUBLIC_KEY,
  6 |   true
  7 | );
```

Well, now I am a bit confused about the error messages that I still see, and therefore would like to hear what do you think it could be the problem?

I check some posts here as well, such as [Typescript react - Could not find a declaration file for module ''react-materialize'. 'path/to/module-name.js' implicitly has an any type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41462729/typescript-react-could-not-find-a-declaration-file-for-module-react-material/43522692) and related
By the way, I am not using typescript.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

.env file should outside the src folder and its work for me  its will also work for you too...

Comment: @Joseph How is this a "thank you" answer? It suggests that the file shouldn't be in the src folder, which looks like an answer to me (though I don't know if it is correct), and though it does seem to be low quality, it still is an answer.

Comment: Thanks for info . I will always  remember this @joseph

Comment: @MarkRotteveel sorry for my mistake

Comment: It was actually that. How clumsy of me, but since I saw other people with the same problem and no one ever mentioned the env file, I completely forgot about it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same error, it went away as soon as I moved the .env file outside the src/ folder. Not using TypeScript either.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some quick steps that should proly help:

- Go the `/src` folder
- And create this file `chec-commerce.d.ts`
  The `d` tells TypeScript that this is a declaration script.
- Inside the just created file, write this:

```js
declare module '@chec/commerce';
```

Based on how you are importing the module, this should clear all the errors.
Kindly confirm.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I already did this before. That's how I fixed the warnings that I got in VS. But the error message that I get when firing the server is still there.

Comment: Are you able to add numbering to the errors for better visibility so that I update the answer here?

Comment: how do you mean?

Comment: I mean update the description to have a list e.g. 1. declare a module, 2, 3 etc

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
export const commerce = new Commerce(process.env.REACT_APP_CHEC_PUBLIC_KEY, true);
```

with

```
export const commerce = new Commerce('PUBLIC_API_KEY', true);
```

I couldn't fix it any other way.