# Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-window'. '/app/node_modules/react-window/dist/index.cjs.js' implicitly has an 'any' type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, yarnpkg, react-window

I've created a react project using `yarn` and `create-react-app` with the typescript template and it worked fine even after installing and using other modules.
After that I used `yarn add react-window` and `yarn add @types/react-window --dev` the following error is raised:

```
yarn run v1.22.5
$ react-scripts build
Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.
/app/src/components/Table.tsx
TypeScript error in /app/src/components/Table.tsx(1,31):
Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-window'. '/app/node_modules/react-window/dist/index.cjs.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm i --save-dev @types/react-window` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'react-window';`  TS7016
  > 1 | import { FixedSizeList } from "react-window";
      |                               ^
    2 | import AutoSizer from "react-virtualized-auto-sizer";
    3 | import InfiniteLoader from "react-window-infinite-loader";
    4 | import { LISTINGS_ENDPOINT } from "../../endpoints";
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Even after running `npm i --save-dev @types/react-window` in my dev environment it still results in the same error.

The app runs in docker and fails on the `RUN yarn build` command. There were no issues prior to using `react-window`.

What is happening? Other posts on stack overflow regarding this error were solved by installing the types modules (for different libraries), or setting `noImplicitAny` to `false` [such as here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43522692/4605629).

Comment: Did `@types/react-window` actually make it into your `package.json`?

Comment: @spender It did but it was under `devDependencies`, the build seems to work now that I manually put it under `dependencies` instead and ran `yarn` again. Should I have used `yarn add @types/react-window` instead of  `yarn add @types/react-window --dev` ?

Comment: It should be a dev-dep, but it shouldn't make too much difference, esp. in a react app where the boundaries are a bit blurry. The packages from both should end up in `node_modules`, and the resolution of those modules at build time depends on them being in `node_modules`. hmm...

Answer (score 1):

please use

```
yarn add @types/react-window --save
```