# Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-tree-graph'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, yarnpkg, npm-package

I am trying to create tree visualization to my react project.
When I added a package 'react-tree-graph' and import Tree module from it:

```
import Tree from 'react-tree-graph'
```

it shows me this error:

> Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-tree-graph'. 'd:/Downloads/CureAssure/F22-011-R-CureAssure/node_modules/react-tree-graph/dist/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
> Try `npm i --save-dev @types/react-tree-graph` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'react-tree-graph';`

I added the package using

```
yarn add react-tree-graph
```

Because I am using Yarn Package Manager.

I thought it might solved by using, npm, So I tried

```
npm install react-tree-graph --save
```

But the error remains same.

I visited the question [Typescript react - Could not find a declaration file for module ''react-materialize'. 'path/to/module-name.js' implicitly has an any type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41462729/typescript-react-could-not-find-a-declaration-file-for-module-react-material), and came to know that the error maybe due to .d.ts file, but I don't know why it is not in the folder.

In node_modules, there exists a folder react-tree-graph with these files:

```
│   CHANGELOG.md
│   LICENSE
│   package.json
│   README.md
│
├───dist
│   │   index.js
│   │   index.min.js
│   │   style.css
│   │   style.min.css
│   │
│   └───module
│       │   d3.js
│       │   index.js
│       │   wrapHandlers.js
│       │
│       └───components
│               animated.js
│               animatedTree.js
│               container.js
│               link.js
│               node.js
│               tree.js
│
├───node_modules
│   └───@babel
├───src
│   │   d3.js
│   │   index.js
│   │   wrapHandlers.js
│   │
│   └───components
│           animated.js
│           animatedTree.js
│           container.js
│           link.js
│           node.js
│           tree.js
│
└───styles
        style.css
```

Answer (score 0):

This is occurring due to unavailability of .ts support still in it. Hopefully it gets merged soon and the issue gets resolved